# Allah's Intervention

Tags: allah, omnipresence

As we all know that Allah intervenes in whatever we do, He is looking at us and nothing can happen without His will. In that case, does Allah own the events like children dying in a bomb as well? And if He does, then isn't it that He does nothing and just watches other people in pain? When we say that Allah loves you more than mother etc. A mother would never watch her children dying in this way.

Then there are people who say that Allah wants you to do something about it etc. My question becomes humans have limitations. I cannot go to Syria into a war zone even if I wanted to, but Allah can do anything! Then why is He silent and letting it happen. And please I want a good answer, not something like "God works in mysterious ways and we can't know anything for sure" or "This place is a test not real etc." the pain that these children and their families face are REAL. Period.

So, kindly let me know your answers on this.

Comment: The answer *is* that it is a test. What more do you want? That doesn't make the pain any less real. In fact, if the pain wasn't real, there would be no test. But, the pain is the test.

Comment: please tell me again why a 3 year old is getting gang raped and burned afterwards in India? What kind of a sick minded test is that?

Comment: The world is test and temporary. So the suffering and pleasure of earth are nothing compare to eternal pleasure of heaven and and eternal suffering of hell. So what's the point of test in earth if Allah keeps helping everyone?

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a chat question, however a very interesting question nevertheless. I, too, have thought about this often, and have come to a conclusion that I see fit personally. You may accept it, or deny it.

Allah (SWT) is all-mighty. He is considered the all-wise and most noble. However, Allah (SWT) does not always intervene in what we do. He is always there and watches us, however He does not always intervene. In the Qur'an, we read stories of the tribes of Prophet Moses and Jesus (PBUT), and it is specifically said that Allah sends these adhab (terrors) to the tribes for not being believers (if you do not know the two stories, I advise that you read them).

However, I believe your question may be targeting more on the side of mosque shootings (God forbid), where people are doing Salat (prayer) and are believers. Allah does not decide that "I am going to kill these people today". Allah is all-merciful as well, he would never want to kill people, and Allah loves us more than our mothers, as you said. Some people are just crazed deviants from the light of Allah, and they do these things. Allah will not have mercy on those who cheat, lie, and kill the innocent, and rather the innocent believers of Islam!

In short, Allah does not intervene in these bombings and shootings. It is the crazed deviants that commit these ill deeds.

Again, a very interesting and intriguing question. Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1):

No, not really. Whilst Allah is Sustainer and Creator of all that it exists, this does not mean that men and women are not responsible for their actions. The Qu'ran says, 'you will certainly be tried.' And then, to be judged.

The question of how Allah sustains the world is an interesting question and is a key question in Islamic philosophy. One of the main conceptions is the Occasionalism of Al-Ghazali who suggested that Allah sustained the very physical laws that makes nature what it is, and hence the very existence of the universe and all life that exists within it possible.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell:

Here is Donya (world), in where we are to be tested by common/natural conditions, not solely with miracle or ... Otherwise, e.g. wouldn't Allah make gravity which can be the cause of falling, etc. So, as I remarked, we are living here to be tested in natural status ...

another part of your query/response: ? "When we say that Allah loves you more than mother etc. A mother would never watch her children dying in this way." ???
E.g. a mother who is very kind, she let doctor to inject her child (by ampoula, also is painful, but knows that it will be better for him/her ... although the root is a test ...

P.S., about dying by bomb: we think it is bad, whereas logically it can be much better for him/her, why? he/she will be dyed in one second, and will be moved to eternity (God willing in the heaven ...) ...

And many other reasons which needs to explain ...

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I have understood, you have asked two different questions...

> ...**does Allah own the events like children dying in a bomb as well?**...

To understand answer to this question, you have to understand two different and fundamental aspects of Islam.

Death is not end of life. This life exists for limited duration.

**Quran 87:16-17**

> No; but you prefer the present life, whereas the Hereafter is better and more enduring.

For a person who thinks that this life is the only life, death and pain are the most scary things. They are unable to understand how God can tolerate death of a young child.

And yet, what is death. It is just a return to Allah. Why is it so terrible?

For a person who refuses to think of anything beyond this life, this life is unjust! Many big criminals who indulged in mass murders lead prosperous life. Many humble people who dedicate themselves to service of society face terrible ends.

I am not saying that death of child in bomb blast is good or desirable. I don't know how to say this. For a believer death of someone close is sad. Yet it is different from what an atheist would feel. For believers death is not **the end**.

A second aspect of this answer is, everything in this world (and next) is in complete control of Allah.

**Quran 5:120**

> To Allah belongs the dominion of the heavens and the earth and all that is in them and He has full power over everything.

Nothing can happen without Allah allowing it to happen. However Allah has given limited freewill to humanity for a limited time.

Allah allows us to take decisions. This leads to many evils that you see in the world. However when Allah allows these evils, it does not mean that Allah supports it. It just means that Allah chooses not to punish the criminals immediately.

In some cases Allah tests people through alteration of good times and calamities.

**Quran 2:155-157**

> We will surely put you to trial by involving you in fear and hunger and by causing loss of property, life and earnings. And give good tidings to those who remain steadfast in these trials: when a misfortune comes to them, they say, "We are Allah's and we shall certainly return to Him", Their Lord will bestow great blessings and mercy upon them; such are the people who are rightly guided.

The second question you have asked is...

> **Then there are people who say that Allah wants you to do something about it etc.**

Who says that? Your responsibilities are related to your abilities.

**Quran 2:286**

> Allah does not burden any human being with a responsibility heavier than he can bear...

You don't have to go anywhere. You have responsibilities where you live. You can spend money in helping poor and old people in your community. Your responsibility might depend on how much money you have! Of course, if you are in position of power, your responsibilities will increase. If you president of your country, you may have obligation towards international peace!

If you feel strongly about what is happening in - for example, Syria, then pray for them. What you pray remains between you and Allah.

**Quran 2:286**

> ..."Our Lord, take us not to task if we forget and lapse into error inadvertently. Lord! lay not on us the kind of burdens that You had lain on the people before us. Lord, lay not on us the kind of burden that we have not the strength to bear. Be kind to us, forgive us and show mercy to us. You are our Protector: help us against the disbelievers."

**Note**: If you are down-voting my answer, you are most welcome. Please provide reasoning in the comments. I promise, I will not argue with you. I am writing this since unexplained down-votes have perplexed me earlier in this forum.